# Group by city name and only display the same city name once in the first row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table

```
city|locality
a   |  bc
a   |  dc
a   |  ef
a   |  gh
a   |  ij
```

I want to create a group by so that it shows

```
a |bc
  |dc
  |ef
  |gh
  |ij
```

I'm currently using

```
select(*) from 'tablename' group by city;
```

but it only gets me one locality value.

Comment: That can not be done by sql

Comment: really what about left join?

Comment: @ReubenGomes you ever get a complete row not a blank and a value

Comment: Is there significance to the empty cells under the `a` or would you be OK with `a` in all the returned cells?

Comment: yea the thing is im using it on my php/html element  has to show a select list with cities the other has to show all the areas... iv considered sending executing 2 sql statements but it doesn't seem efficient

Comment: You do realise that you can fix this problem in your presentation layer, right.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I did that only  thing is from start i had statc elements now  i needed dynamic elements and dint want to alter the presentation layer but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty sure if this is what you want, but if you want to get all rows from `locality` for `a` in one new cell, you can use this.

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(locality) as localities FROM table GROUP BY city
```

This will output:

```
city    localities 
a       bc, dc, ef, gh, ij
```

Comment: iv treid this but  it does solve the problem  ..the thing is i have to run a clean up function to print in my script line by line for loacalities

Comment: Why not to fix this problem by PHP in your output?

Comment: yea i just did that made it easier i just concated with   // between values  .....seperator  ...it just struck me what my array will look like in the event that i do manage to get what i want

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to just use:

```
select city, locality from yourtable order by city, locality
```

You can then solve the problem in your presentation layer by only printing/using `city` if the value changes.

Something like (in Java):

```java
String previousCity = null;
while (rs.next()) {
    String currentCity = rs.getString("city");
    if (Objects.equals(previousCity, currentCity) {
        // Same as previous: no need to print so set blank
        String currentCity = "";
    } else {
        previousCity = currentCity;
    }

    System.out.println(currentCity + " | " + rs.getString("locality"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select col1, GROUP_CONCAT(col2 SEPARATOR ';') from tablename;
```

It will give you the result like:

a | bc;dc;ef;gh;ij

Now use it in your own way.

Answer (score -1):

You can try by writing 2 queries,

```
select distinct (city) from 'tablename';
```

then u will get city as 'a';

```
select * from tablename where city='a';// 'a' means out put of first query
```

Comment: That is really inefficient